# Is there a way to insert a path of the file instead of opening it with CtrlP plugin?

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

I'm using [ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) to open files by fuzzy search.

Is there a way to get the full path of the searched file and insert it under cursor, instead of opening it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customize the function handling the opening of files, as explained at `:help 'g:ctrlp_open_func'`.
You could try something similar to this:

```
function! CtrlPOpenFunc(action, line)
   if a:action =~ '^h$'    
      " Get the filename
      let filename = fnameescape(fnamemodify(a:line, ':p'))

      " Close CtrlP
      call ctrlp#exit()
      call ctrlp#mrufiles#add(filename)

      " insert the contents of filename into the buffer
      put =filename
   else    
      " Use CtrlP's default file opening function
      call call('ctrlp#acceptfile', [a:action, a:line])

   endif
endfunction

let g:ctrlp_open_func = { 
         \ 'files': 'CtrlPOpenFunc',
         \ 'mru files': 'CtrlPOpenFunc' 
         \ }
```

, in order to insert the file path by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> in the Ctrlp window.

Answer (score 2):

This is <s>really</s> hacky, but it worked for me, if you source this mapping

```
nnoremap <Leader>pf :let @p=expand("%")<CR>:tabclose<CR>"pp
```

then

1. put your cursor where you want the filename to be put
2. use <kbd>Ctrl + p</kbd>, as normal to find your file, then open the file in a new tab
   (open a file in a new tab from inside Ctrl-p is <kbd>Ctrl + t</kbd>)
3. run my leader mapping `<Leader>pf`

the mapping will assign the file that Ctrl-p opened to the `p` register, close the tab and paste the `p` register where your cursor was.